# calling renderWith() on a DataObject inside an Extension

Tags: php, silverstripe

Since upgrading from Silverstripe 3.0 to 3.1, rendering a DataObject with a template does no longer work.

I extended a ModelAdmin to display some rather complex markup (some data table) *inside its edit form*.

```
SSViewer::set_theme('mytheme');
Requirements::clear();
$form->Fields()->insertAfter(
    new HtmlEditorField_Readonly(
        'Title', 
        '', 
        //render DataObject with template inside the form
        $analytics->renderWith('MyTpl')
    ), 
    'SomeField'
);
Requirements::restore();
```

That worked beautifully before the upgrade and now fails with:

> [User Warning] None of these templates can be found in theme
>   'mytheme': MyTpl.ss

(Template file does exist though)

Is there anything wrong with rendering a DataObject with a templates in this context?
Any ideas on why that wouldn't work or how to fix it?

Comment: What is the directory path to MyTpl.as? Have you tried calling ?flush=all on the page you get the warning on?

Comment: It had been in a subfolder called `templates/order` (which wasn't a problem in 3.0). But i also tried `/templates` `/templates/Includes` and `templates/Layout` (with flush=all respectively)

Comment: Is you template in a theme or in your mysite/module folder. If in a theme, is the right theme enabled? Moving it under mysite/templates might help. Also, check with ?showtemplate to see which templates are available.

Comment: thanks! - putting it under "mysite/templates/mysubfolder" did the trick. I didn't even know you could have global templates :/ glad to get rid of the whole `set_theme/clear-requirements` hack. Maybe you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above you could (or should, some could argue) place your templates under `mysite/templates/...` (especially if they are for the cms) if you have themes enabled (am pretty sure) SS looks into that theme folder first for templates which can sometime be annoying and create caching issues...

I personally don't use themes anymore, I just have everything under `mysite` which I actually call something relevant to my project, keeps things tidy and easy to publish.

Note: themes are still useful, but maybe more for site that would change design, like e-commerce site with a xmass theme for example. I think there was a discussion about this on SilverScoop...

Comment: those were shared templates... (cms uses frontend tpl to render some data table). But I really do like the "no-theme approach" and keep everything under the mysite folder, which I name `_[projectname]` to have it on top of my directory list in the IDE ;)  +1 & thanks !